# Displaying the attributes of another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-4-2-1

I have two models: `User` and `Role`.
The User attributes are:

```
name:string
email:string 
admin:boolean 
role_id:integer
```

The Role attributes are:

```
designer:boolean 
developer:boolean
```

The associations that I've set is that user `belongs_to` role and role `has_many` users. 
When the user signs up, I want him to choose his position (either designer or developer). However, I get the `role_id` as an Integer field when I want to display the positions (designer and developer) to choose from. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: The bit where you use: `admin:boolean`, `designer:boolean`, and `developer:boolean` really makes my eyes hurt. I suggest you re-think your design.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called "[Nested Models](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models)".

First you have to tell the model to allow the other model like this:

```
# app/model/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :role
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :role
end
```

the next thing is in your view

```
#app/views/users/new.html.ham
= simple_form_for @user do |f| 
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :email
  %br
  = f.simple_fields_for :role do |role|
    = role.input :designer
    = role.input :developer
  = f.button :submit, "Send Message", :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-block'
```

Now last but bot least you to be able to accept the new params in the controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  expose(:users){User.all.order(:id)}
  expose(:user, attributes: :user_params)

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.role.build
  end

  def create
    if user.save
      flash[:notice] = t(:user_was_successfully_created)
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      [
        :email ,
        :name ,
        role_attributes: [
          :designer,
          :developer,
        ]
      ]
    )
  end
end
```

you can look at a sample app https://github.com/mzaragoza/sample_nestes_forms

I hope that this helps 
Happy Hacking